# Cosine similarity of averaged random word vectors

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings

I am trying to find the cosine similarity (using glove vector) of two random words. As expected, the distribution of the similarity concentrated around 0 since it is reasonable to think that two random words will not be similar to each other.

However, when I try to do a similar thing to 2 random sets of 10 words, that is I take the average vector of the 10 words in both sets and calculate the cosine similarity, the similarity tends to concentrate at 0.8.

It seems to suggest that given 2 random sentences of 10 words, they are very likely to be similar semantically. What could be the explanation of this?

Included python code to reproduce the result.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

vocab = nlp.vocab
words = np.array([x.orth_.encode('utf8') for x in vocab])

hist1 = []
n = 1000
num_words = 1
for _ in range(n):
    x,y = choice(words, size=(2,num_words))
    x = nlp(" ".join([u.decode('utf8') for u in x]))
    y = nlp(" ".join([u.decode('utf8') for u in y]))
    s = x.similarity(y)
    hist1.append(s)

hist10 = []
n = 1000
num_words = 10
for _ in range(n):
    x,y = choice(words, size=(2,num_words))
    x = nlp(" ".join([u.decode('utf8') for u in x]))
    y = nlp(" ".join([u.decode('utf8') for u in y]))
    s = x.similarity(y,)
    hist10.append(s)

plt.hist([hist1,hist10], label=[1,10])
plt.legend()
```

[image: Distribution of cosine similarity]

Comment: Interesting observation! You are finding that naive averaging does not yield good document embeddings in the sense that cosine similarities are not centered. I don't know how you would explain _why_ it happens, but I might know a fix: subtract the first principal component, as suggested in [A Simple but Tough-to-Beat Baseline for Sentence Embeddings](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SyK00v5xx). Welcome to the site! P.S. Are you sure you are averaging and not concatenating the words?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too surprising here. As you sample more and more words, the sample mean is a better and better estimator of the population mean. This is called the law of large numbers.

Comment: I am surprised that it converges this rapidly, consider that I only sample 10 words from millions of English words